# ClassNotFoundException com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory Jaxb-Impl

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to update the `jax-impl` class from version `1.0.6` to a more recent version in order to be compatible with `jaxb-runtime:2.3.1` because of the following message:

> java.lang.LinkageError: You are trying to run JAXB 2.0 runtime (from jar:file:/opt/tomcat/appName/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.class) but you have old JAXB 1.0 runtime earlier in the classpath (at jar:file:/opt/tomcat/appName/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-1.0.6.jar!/com/sun/xml/bind/WhiteSpaceProcessor.class) Please remove the JAXB 1.0 runtime for 2.0 runtime to work correctly.

After increasing the version of `jaxb-impl` to any newer version, I get the following complaint:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1

This occurs because of a call to the `JAXBContext.newInstance` method using a context path as an argument:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance('package.name')
```

`newInstance` calls using a class as an argument still work fine.

Is there a solution to the ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 exception when upgrading Jaxb-Impl?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory class in the jaxb-impl v2.3.1 jars. Are you missing a dependency?

It sounds like you should be calling: com.sun.xml.bind.**v2**.ContextFactory

Maybe you still have a dependency that is outdated and calling the old class.